# Ornamental spin or array?

Tags: modeling

How would you model this ornament? I've tried using an array on a cube with an object offset to an empty. Which works for one of the branches, but I cant figure out how to make them spiral as seen in the picture.

[image]

Comment: if you can make it for one of the branches, you could parent an empty to your complete branch (all objects), copy it and just rotate it

Answer (score 2):

Create your object, create an empty at the exact same position, give your object an *Array* modifier with the empty as *Object Offset*, move the empty away from its initial position and rotate it a bit:

[image]

Create a second empty at the same position as your object, give your object a second *Array* modifier with this second empty as *Object Offset*, again move and rotate this empty:

[image]